# ESM import resulting in "Cannot resolve path" in IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, es6-modules

Using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2, Build #IU-213.6777.52

IntelliJ is complaining of `Cannot resolve directory 'webpack'` when encountering the following line in my webpack.config.js file.

```
import ModuleFederationPlugin from 'webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin.js';
```

This is how the IDE is highlighting my import:

[image: Image showing IntelliJ Idea unable to resolve path]

No issues at build or runtime, and when I Command-Click on this import, it takes me to the `ModuleFederationPlugin.js` file in my `node_modules` folder.

Comment: and what is `webpack` here? a  folder in your project, or? The path is neither a relative path nor a module name, such paths can only be resolved if some path mappings are defined

Comment: `webpack` _is_ a module name. It is included in my devDependencies. The build works fine. IntelliJ is not recognizing the import as a deep path within a module as it should.